# If $B=5I_2-3A+A^2$ can I show this matrix is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $D=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 0 & 7 \end{pmatrix}$, then $A=PDP^{-1}$ and $B=5I-3A+A^2$. Show that B is diagonalizable.

I have tried algebraically, trying to get $B^{-1}$, but get nothing.

Comment: Are you trying to show $B$ is invertible (as the title indicates) or diagonizable (as the question body indicates)?

Comment: @Daniel G. Ulate Montero Let $\mathbf{A}$ be any commutative ring and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be an arbitrary natural number. If the square matrix of order $n$ $M \in \mathscr{M}_n(\mathbf{A})$ is diagonalisable -- which means there exists an invertible $U \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{A})$ such that $UMU^{-1}$ be a *diagonal* matrix -- then for any polynomial $f \in \mathbf{A}[X]$ the matrix $f(M)$ is also diagonalisable, since $Uf(M)U^{-1}=f\left(UMU^{-1}\right)$ and in particular $f(D)$ remains diagonal as long as $D$ is diagonal. More specifically, *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @Daniel G. Ulate Montero *(cont.)*, if for arbitrary $\lambda \in \mathbf{A}^n$ we denote by $\mathrm{D}(\lambda)$ the diagonal matrix whose diagonal is given by the $n$-tuple $\lambda$ -- more explicitly, such that $\mathrm{D}(\lambda)_{kl}=\lambda_k\delta_{kl}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the *Kronecker delta* -- then for any polynomial $f \in \mathbf{A}[X]$ one has $f\left(\mathrm{D}(\lambda)\right)=\mathrm{D}\left(f(\lambda)\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A=PDP^{-1}$, $P^{-1}AP=D$,

so $P^{-1}BP=P^{-1}(5I-3A+A^2)P=P^{-1}(5I)P-3P^{-1}(A)P+P^{-1}(A^2)P$

$=5I-3D+D^2$, which is diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you another simple proof. From $D$, we can find 2 and 7 are eigenvalues of $A$. By using the equation, we can find $B$ have eigenvalues 3 and 33. Since they are distinct, $B$ is also diagonalizable.